# "SettingWithCopyWarning" with pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, copy, warnings

```
Test 1.1.2
C:\Users\742093\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:670: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
Test 1.1.3
```

```
    print("Test 1.1.2")
    df = pd.read_csv( r''+file+'', sep=";", engine='python'  ) #open the file and read
    print("Test 1.1.3")
```

As you can see the warning appears right at the read_csv-line. But I have no clue what this warning means in my case or how to fix it. It must have something to do with the data in the file I'm loading (I load other files to with no problem).

Comment: Is there more to your code before this? It would be great if you could post some of it. Usually this warning happens when you're modifying a copy of something. See here for more details: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: This sounds strange to be honest. Why are you using *engine='python'* with a simple *sep=";"*?

Comment: @bld: Yes there is code before and after it. However the error is clearly thrown at the read_csv-line and has something to do with the data that is loaded (a 20MB csv file). Other csv files are loaded in the loop before with no error.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny: The german version of Excel exports csv with the semicolon separator. Changing the engine is an idea I will test. However I made the best experience with "python" up to this point.